# Disabled bootstrap.js, and know my links work, but I need bootstrap.js, what do I do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I figured out that bootstrap.js is casuing my a href's not to work but I need bootstrap.js for my design. 
here is one of the profiles of my site http://21stca.com.fodasign.co/profiles/the-ojays.html
username:af
password:soccer222

so click connect on the side bar and try to click the facebook icon nothing happens unless I disable bootstrap but I don't want to do that I feel like this is an easy fix, but I can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.connect-buttons a').unbind()
```

There seems to be a function overlap somewhere, so force the default function on the element. If this doesn't solve the problem, then there's probably a class-related problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, im .js illiterate, where do I put that in my code?

Comment: In your html file, at the bottom of the page just before the <body> ends, like this:
    `<script>$('.connect-buttons a').unbind()</script>`